# template for typedef that accepts pointer to both const and non-const functions

Tags: c++, c++14, pointer-to-member

Here is the pointer to a class method that accepts two ints and returns an int:

```
template <typename T>
using TFunction = int (T::*)(int, int);
```

I can only pass here non-const methods.
How to change this template such a way that it will accept both const and non-const methods?

Comment: You mean *either* `const` and non-`const` functions, right? No single pointer type can do both at the same time.

Comment: I doesn't accept *any* member. It accepts a `T`. You went too minimal on your [mcve]. This is an XY question.

Comment: You can't have a name that refers to 2 types at the same time. You can do `template <typename T> using TCFunction = int (T::*const)(int, int);` to have a name for `const` functions or you type-erase the function pointers with `std::function` or your own version.

Answer (score 6):

This case is simple enough for a conditional:

```
template <typename T>
using TFunction = std::conditional_t<
    std::is_const_v<T>,
    int (T::*)(int, int) const,
    int (T::*)(int, int)
>;
```

Now `TFunction<Foo>` is `int (Foo::*)(int, int)`, and `TFunction<Foo const>` is `int (Foo::*)(int, int) const`.

Comment: But what about non-const Foo types with constant member functions?

Comment: @Jodocus that's a red herring: I'm piggybacking the "`const`-or-non-`const`" parameter onto `T` instead of making it, say, a separate `bool`. It has nothing to do with the `const`ness of the actual `Foo` you'll use later, you'll still be able to call a `TFunction<Foo const>` onto a `Foo` :)

Comment: Deleted my original comment because this is brilliant. Even though in general `T` has to be an id-expression (and as such can't be `const T` in general), the template context allows to both use the type information, *and* keep the pointer to member well formed.